# pytube KeyError: 's'

Tags: python, youtube, pytube

Хочу изучить модуль pytube, но, на первой же строчке возникает ошибка:

```
    signature = cipher.get_signature(js, stream['s'])
KeyError: 's'
```

Код:

```
import pytube

yt = pytube.YouTube('https://youtu.be/rGJCRNLv_20')
print(yt.title)
```

Comment: Это известная проблема. Говорят, что youtube время от времени меняет  способ представления подписи в URL, и pytube просто ещё не успело обновиться. Вы можете самостоятельно поправить файлы pytube, как описано здесь:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56548629/pytube-v-9-5-0-signature-error-in-mixins-py  У меня этот способ сработал.

Comment: @Xander Пожалуйста, добавьте это как ответ, я помечу это галочкой

Comment: Попробуйте вывести содержимое stream через print, посмотрите что там вообще есть.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это известная проблема. Говорят, что youtube время от времени меняет способ представления подписи в URL, и pytube просто ещё не успело обновиться. Вы можете самостоятельно поправить файлы pytube.

Нужно в файле mixins.py исправить:

```
if 'signature=' in url:
```

на

```
if ('signature=' in url) or ('&sig=' in url) or ('&lsig=' in url):
```